# as3 how do I stop when colliding when i'm using this movement

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using a different type of movement, without using vx or vy, because it sort of messes up my movement. Instead I just used regular numbers, but then when I collide the hittest will not work. Is there a specific way on how I should hittest?

On key down event listener:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        isRight = true
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        isLeft = true
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
        isUp = true
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        isDown = true
    }
```

On key up event listener:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        isRight = false
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        isLeft = false
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
        isUp = false
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        isDown = false
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
```

On enterframe:

```
if (isRight == true)
    {
        x += 5;
        play();
    }
    if (isLeft == true )
    {
        x -= 5;
        play();
    }
    if (isUp == true)
    {
        y -= 5;
        play();
    }
    if (isDown == true)
    {
        y += 5;
        play();
    }
```

I don't know how I should oganize my hitTestObject in order to work properly.

```
if (player.hitTestObject(brick)
{
    player.x -= ?
    player.y -= ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to achieve but if you want your player to bounce back from the brick so that it no longer triggers hit test just try to move it in direction opposite to the brick like:

```
var dx = player.x - brick.x;
var dy = player.y - brick.y;  
player.x += dx/Math.abs(dx)*5;
player.y += dy/Math.abs(dy)*5;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to save the position of the character on the previous frame. i.e. have variables:

```
previousX = player.x;
previousY = player.y;
```

Then when the character is moved and runs into the brick, you can just revert their x position back to the previous one.

```
//code makes player move
if(player.hitTestObject(wall)){
    player.x=previousX;
}
```

After all hit tests are complete, then you can update the `previousX` and `previousY` variables for the next frame.

You may need to add additional checks using this method to determine whether the obstacle was hit from above/below or from the side by comparing the positions of the obstacle and player.

Comment: It doesn't make any changes seeing that previousX is the same exact position as player.x and not the previous position.

Comment: @Crook The idea is that you set the `previousX` and `previousY` values, THEN move the character (e.g. `player.x+=10`). If the character has moved into a barrier, you move them back (e.g. `player.x=previousX`). This moving back and forward will not be perceived by the user as it happens to quickly, they will simply see the player not move forward. After all collision detections are made, the `previousX` and `previousY` can be updated.